# Android Studio Alertdialog show image full size

Tags: android

I want to the show Full size of the image in the alert dialog, When I click on the imagebutton in the android project. How can I do?

Comment: add your code and the image that u  getting for more info..

Comment: share screenshot and code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/my_image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In activity show your custom dialog box using below code -

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
builder.setView(dialogView)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.create, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    }).create().show();
```

Comment: Also see this link for more information http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score -1):

transaction to new fragment with a imageview in match parent.